# How to i derive the owner account of an ATA (given the ATA)

Tags: spl-token-program

One example will be the SyncNative instruction in Token Program - it gives the ATA but I want to retrieve the owner. [image: how do I derive owner given this?]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getAccount` from `@solana/spl-token` to retrieve information about a token account, which includes the owner of the token account

```
  let tokenAccount = await getAccount(connection, new PublicKey("..."))
  console.log(tokenAccount.owner.toBase58())
```

Comment: how can i find the owner if the account is closed?